# insert record from another table with auto increment column new table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, auto-increment

I have to insert record from a table with `auto_increment` id field.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_rg_lead_detail` 
WHERE lead_id =59;
UPDATE tmptable SET lead_id =60 WHERE lead_id =59;
insert into `wp_rg_lead_detail` (`id`, `lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value`)
    select `id`, `lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value`
    from `tmptable`
    WHERE lead_id =60;
```

> Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

I need auto_increment filed `id` in target table should increment by above query.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why can't you just update `lead_id` in `wp_rg_lead_detail`?

Comment: I have to insert record from another table with auto incrementing new table id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't insert the ID, and let the autoincremenet property of the column handle it:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_rg_lead_detail` 
(`lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value`) -- No Id!
SELECT `lead_id`, `form_id`, `field_number`, `value`
FROM   `tmptable`
WHERE  `lead_id` = 60;
```